# How to edit Facebook graph object attributes (i.e video title)?

Tags: facebook, graph, edit, koala

I'm using ruby Koala, and trying to find how can I edit an existing object's attributes via Facebook graph.

All I could find at Facebook documentation is:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#update

But didn't find it helpful.

Thanks!
Moozly.

Comment: what response did you get back when you ran that code from your link you posted?

Comment: I didn't see how I can use this code updating my graph object.

Comment: Did you even try to run any of those commands?

Comment: I didn't understand how does that code fit my app code and graph objects?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `#graph_call` method of `Koala::Facebook::API`? I got this to work for updating a page event for example:

```
graph.graph_call("/#{some_id}", hash_of_attributes_to_change, 'post')
```

As suggested in the Facebook documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question here's how it should be done:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new oauth_access_token
response = graph.put_connections(object_id, path, params)
# check the response
response.is_a?(Hash) && response["success"] == true
```